# Why variable value is getting changed unusually

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2005

I have a code like this,In this context HandleDisconnectEventCB will trigger when client has some modified whithout saved data and disconnected(remove network cable) from server,,then it will make 'clientWithLock= 0' and will remove from collection that is shown below code. But now the problem is  other connected clients cannot make changes,it showing that 'clientWithLock' has some data not zero,due to that it will show another user is updating data please wait.Is there any badlogic going on here

```
private static int clientWithLock = 0;

static private void HandleDisconnectEventCB(SPD.SPD_serverLocationType loc,
                                            string server, int clientId,
                                            object passback)
{
    // Remove lock if necessary
    if (clientWithLock == clientId) clientWithLock = 0;

    // Remove client from client list and end replicated display sessions
    for (int i = 0; i < clients.Count; i++)
    {
        SPURTclient sc = (SPURTclient)clients[i];
        if (sc.ClientId == clientId)
        {
            .
            .
            clients.RemoveAt(i);
            break;
```

Comment: Please update your question and use some punctuation in your sentences. It's very hard to read it...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Making clientwithlock static is going to cause you all kinds of headaches here if you have multiple disconnects in rapid succession. I'd recommend either making the whole operation stateless, so 'ClientWithLock' is passed as a parameter to the event, and you operate the static function based on all parameters passed. If 'ClientWithLock' is updated twice in fast succession for disconnects, behaviour will be quite strange.

Or, instancing the whole class and operation so the disconnection handler is instanced on a class by class basis if having the whole thing stateless is not an option for you.

Comment: i didnt get you what you mean by making whole operation stateless

Comment: having:
 private static int clientWithLock = 0;

in your class, as static, is putting a state on the class, clientWithLock can only have 1 value across ALL instances (if the class is non-static, if the class is static, then the only instance of the class, can only have 1 concurrent value for clientWithLock) by making this a parameter on your event instead of a static variable, you remove the 'State' from the class, using clientWithLock on an event by event basis, which is far more efficient and I suspect will correct the strange behaviour you're seeing.

Comment: Here The variable 'clientwithlock' and event HandleDisconnectEven are coming under class  'public class SPURTServer'

Comment: cool, so either remove 'Static' from clientwithlock, or change it to a parameter of all events that use it, and remove its declaration at the class level.

Comment: So you mean make clientWithLock as int variable rather than static that means 
private  int clientWithLock = 0; rather than private static int clientWithLock = 0;
Will it make any harmful effects

Comment: i will use 'int clientWithLock = 0;' whereever clientWithLock used .Does that a optimized way or??

Comment: any way great,,it is working fine ,, i was thinking why unusual

Comment: That's pretty optimal if you're not using a static class. if you're unsure why a variable is static, it probably shouldn't be.